# Why does Flow in VS Code give two type definitions for my React function?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, flowtype

I'm using Flow and React to create an Azure Static App in VS Code. The app works, but I'm confused by the type definitions of my functions. I've created a small example in a file annotated with `//@flow strict`

```js
function WhyMismatch(): React.MixedElement {
  return <h1></h1>
}
```

Please refer to [this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTqv0.png) The code yields the following two type signatures in the UI.

- `function WhyMismatch(): any`
- `() => MixedElement`

Note the two definitions. Why does the first list the return type as `any`? Did I apply the return wrong type or misconfigure something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of them is the TypeScript definition because vscode and TS are both shipped by Microsoft they basically baked the TS intellisense straight into the application. You can turn it off in the settings but there really is no need and you can usually tell which is which.

In your case, the one that says `function(): any` is TS because it doesn't understand `React.MixedElement`

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.

Comment: You're very welcome! Don't forget to mark the answer as the solution so people know it's answered. And if you have any more questions on flowtype you can reach out on discord too :)